# Migrating from local to live wordpress asks for new installation

Tags: wordpress

I have finished developing a wordpress site in xampp environment. I decided to go live with it so I zipped all the files in the htdocs/sitename/ directory and uploaded it into public_html directory of live website and then extracted the contents. Then I exported local website database and imported it to the live website.

Now when I visit the live website address, instead of seeing the home page of the website, I encounter the very first page of installing a fresh copy of wordpress (which asks for selecting a language to start installing wordpress)! Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The table prefixes of live website database was different from the table prefix set in the wp-config.php file. So, I changed the $table_prefix variable in wp-config.php file to match the live database table prefixes. Problem solved.